# Проблемма с vagrant virtualbox на ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

При попытке выполнения команды vagrant up получаю такую ошибку:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface:
VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Версия vagrant и virtualbox последние. Все решения которые находил вели к тому что нужно обновить virtualbox и vagrant или просто перезапустить virtualbox. Перезапуск так же не помог. Вообщем надеюсь на вашу помощь.